# How to get the virtual machine name that my app is running on in azure

Tags: java, azure

I have a java application running on an azure virtual machine
Is there an API to get details on this VM?
Specifically I need to get the VM name

Comment: `System.out.println(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());`

Comment: getLocalHost fails when running on azure vm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a REST API you can use that I found in Azure's docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/get.

Usually from within the guest OS you cannot retrieve any sensitive information about the underlying VM without using external APIs because that will be a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks. but one of the parameters I have to supply is the vmName, which is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: You're right, in that case what you can do is to list all VMs using similar API and filter by any available criteria that you can provide. Probably by IP address. But of course this will be time consuming if you have a thousand VMs